# How can i count images per album in php

Tags: php, mysql

How can i count upload images per album based on user id..i have done this but is not ok..some help is appreciated. I'm new learner!

Here is what i have:

```
     Album db: |albumid|name|image|uid| <- user id 
     Gallery db: |galleryid|albumid|name|images|uid|
```

Code

```
 $sql = "
    SELECT COUNT(userid) 
      FROM tbl_gallery 
     where userid = 1
    ";
    $rs_result = mysql_query($sql,$con);
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($rs_result);
    $total_records = $row[0];
    echo $total_records;

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_album where userid = 1 ORDER BY albumid";
    $rs_result = mysql_query($sql,$con);


    ####### Fetch Results From Table ########

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_result)) 
    {
        $aimage=$row['image'];
        $aid=$row['albumid'];
        $aname=$row['name'];

        <div class="pic">
    <?php 
        echo "<a href='includes/galeriefoto/gallery.php?id=1'> <img src='includes/galeriefoto/admin/acatch/$aimage' class='thumbimg' alt='Pic' alt='$aname'>"; 
    ?>
        <span class='pic-caption'>

            <center><p style='color:#000;font-size:24px'><?php echo $aname;?> (<?php echo $total_records;?>)</p></center>

        </span></a>
        </div>
   <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
 database extension in new code
 **[this happens](https://media.giphy.com/media/kg9t6wEQKV7u8/giphy.gif)**
 it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.
If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions and prepared statements.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: thanks for the reply and guidance..can u help me with this?

Comment: no explanation of what's not working, but its probably misuse of mysql_ because the sql query looks ok enough

Comment: Your SQL query doesn't seem to correspond to the database _schemas_ you've outlined. What's `uid` and where's `userid`? Are these the same field? What's `images`? Is this a single image or a JSON object of images? Please clarify your question and the information you're providing further and consider providing sample data for each table.

Comment: uid = user id that upload the image or creating the album and images is the path of the image (single image) not json

Comment: You still need to let us know _what_ it is that doesn't work. _"but is not ok"_ is _not_ enough information. What's the expected result and what result are you currently getting?

Comment: What dsnt work is the counting of pictures from albums and what i want is this: Album 1 (32 Pictures) - album 2 (3 pictures) - and so on...

Comment: The code from the top is returning me this: http://i.imgur.com/MLgnInH.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is just about counting the number of images in an album, the following would suffice for your query:

```
SELECT uid, albumid, COUNT(galleryid) as num_upload_images
FROM tbl_gallery
GROUP BY uid, albumid
```

This results in the following possible output:

```
[0] => [
    uid => 1,
    albumid => 1,
    num_upload_images => 15
],
[1] => [
    uid => 1,
    albumid => 2,
    num_upload_images => 12
]
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, is showing me () , noting ,empty

Comment: Does it return empty as well when executing this query on the database as well?

Comment: In the database i see is return ok

Comment: So this means that the query is good but the implementation of the code is wrong. Can you provide the PHP code with the updated query?

Comment: $sql = "SELECT uid, albumid, COUNT(galleryid) as num_upload_images FROM tbl_gallery WHERE uid = 1 GROUP BY uid, albumid";
$rs_result = mysql_query($sql,$con);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($rs_result);
$total_records = $row[0];
echo $total_records;

Comment: I think you are echoing an array with `$total_records`. could you do:
`echo '<pre>'; print_r($row); print_r($row[0]);`
And output that result